# Why can't I open a file when I use glob on a directory with a space in the name?

Tags: perl

I recently started working with Perl as a requirement for an education class. Part of our homework is to open a text file, read some lines, and then close the file.

I created a folder on the desktop and put the required text files in it. I wrote the following code to open each file, read a line, and close it:

```
my $dir = 'C:\Users\Jay Zabaluski\Desktop\Shakespeare';

opendir (DIR, $dir) or die "cannot opendir $dir";

foreach my $fp (glob("$dir/*.txt")) {

  printf "%s\n", $fp;

  open my $fh, "<", $fp or die "can't read open '$fp': $OS_ERROR";
  my $firstLine = <$fh>;
  print "$firstLine\n";

  close $fh or die "can't read close '$fp': $OS_ERROR";
}
```

When I run this script on Padre, the Perl IDE, I get this error:

```
C:./UsersJay
can't read open 'C:./UsersJay': at example.pl line 5
Press any key to continue.....
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error unless I'm somehow mistakenly using `\` instead of `/`, but when I right-click on a file in Windows Explorer, the path always shows up with backslashes, e.g. `C:\something\something`.

I tried changing the file path to use forward slashes as suggested by OnlineCop in the comments, but got a similar error:

```
C:/Users/Jay
can't read open 'C:/Users/Jay': at example.pl line 5
Press any key to continue.....
```

Comment: You *may* need to escape your '\' character: '\\'. Many languages support forward slashes instead of backslashes in paths, so `my $dir = 'C:/Users/Jay Zabaluski/Desktop/Shakespeare';` would be just as valid, without requiring you to escape the backslashes.

Comment: @OnlineCop - i proceeded to change the path to the one you suggested, however now i get this error: C:/Users/Jay
can't read open 'C:/Users/Jay': at example.pl line 5
Press any key to continue.....

Comment: Edit your original post with any new information you find.

Comment: Escape the space after `Jay` as `Jay\ Zabaluski`

Comment: @nu11p01n73R - I proceeded to do that so the path changed to C:\Users\Jay\ Zabaluski\Desktop\Shakespeare but now it just proceeded to say cannot opendir. guess it sucks to have a last name along with a first name for windows haha

Comment: You cannot glob a path that has space in it. Space is the delimiter in glob.

Comment: You also don't need to `opendir` _and_ `glob`

Comment: And also, `opendir` and glob are two different ways of doing a similar thing. You would use one or the other: Not both.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for all your help! Don't understand whoever gave it a -1. If you are going to get down voted for asking a question on a language you are really new at, people are going to just be scared to ask any questions.

Comment: @user2128074 Don't worry about a single downvote, it just means that one person out of the 31 who have viewed your question so far didn't like it. (Note that you also got two upvotes.) However, when I first saw your question, I was about to downvote and vote to close as unclear, because you didn't show the code that was causing your error. The best anyone could do is guess at what your problem was. Then I checked the edit history and saw that you removed the code in an earlier edit...please don't do that! I've re-added the code to your question, along with some other minor improvements.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Sorry about that :(

Comment: @user2128074 It's okay, Stack Overflow has a bit of learning curve. If you make sure your questions are clear, reasonably scoped, and well formatted, you will tend to get upvotes and, more importantly, decent answers. Good luck with your class!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach my $fp (glob qq("$dir/*.txt")) {
```

---

`perldoc -f glob` :

```
Note that "glob" splits its arguments on whitespace and treats
each segment as separate pattern. As such, "glob("*.c *.h")"
matches all files with a .c or .h extension. The expression
"glob(".* *")" matches all files in the current working directory.
If you want to glob filenames that might contain whitespace,
you'll have to use extra quotes around the spacey filename to
protect it. For example, to glob filenames that have an "e"
followed by a space followed by an "f", use either of:
```

```perl
            @spacies = <"*e f*">;
            @spacies = glob '"*e f*"';
            @spacies = glob q("*e f*");
```

```
 If you had to get a variable through, you could do this:
```

```perl
            @spacies = glob "'*${var}e f*'";
            @spacies = glob qq("*${var}e f*")
```

Comment: It is reasonable to include sections of relevant documentation, but a solution that contains *only* a copy of other people's work is lazy. The Stack Overflow archive is intended to be a resource that anyone can search for a resolution to similar problems. If you provide nothing but clips from the internet then you are spoiling that ambition.

Comment: I have no ambition to waste my time.  Sometimes it is fully sufficient to know which short fragment should be copied&pasted.  My goal is to teach how to increase chances of finding next answer without asking in public.

Comment: Thanks Andrzej for the resume of the documentation. I think it's important to read this useful notes that clever people wrote for make easier our work. Sometimes functions doesn't work the way we imagine.

Comment: I am not going to pretend I always remember all strange "implementation details" :-)

Answer (score 4):

As others have observed, the problem is that your call to `glob`

```
glob("$dir/*.txt")
```

uses this definition of `$dir`

```
my $dir = 'C:\Users\Jay Zabaluski\Desktop\Shakespeare';
```

so the call is equivalent to this

```
glob('C:\Users\Jay Zabaluski\Desktop\Shakespeare/*.txt')
```

So the parameter has two components, `C:\Users\Jay` and `Zabaluski\Desktop\Shakespeare/*.txt`, which isn't at all what you meant.

The solution is to enclose the entire wildcard pattern in double quotes, so you could use the `qq` operator to define a new delimiter, different from `"`, that will interpolate embedded variables.

For example, try

```
my $glob_pattern = qq{"$dir/*.txt"};
say $glob_pattern;
```

and you will see that the parameter *actually* passed to `glob` is

```
"C:\Users\Jay Zabaluski\Desktop\Shakespeare/*.txt"
```

*including* the double quotes, which are essential.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer sir! I am sorry, i am pretty new at Perl so knowing these little things will take some time for me :)

Comment: @user2128074: That is hardly a *little thing*. It has caught me several times, and isn't at all obvious. The problem is that Perl's `glob` tries to emulate the Bourne shell's filename expansion, which is far from being intuitive, especially on platforms other than Linux.

Comment: I see, so if i am trying to access a directory in linux, would the q/qq not be needed if there is a space in between names of directories?

Comment: @user2128074: I don't believe that Linux will be any different. The discrepancy is that Perl's `glob` is coded to behave the same way as the Bourne shell's filename expansion. What it does on any other platform is pretty much undefined. You should experiment: it's not a difficult thing to try.